# Sparse Matrix implemantation and operations in java

Tags: java, sparse-matrix, decomposition

I have to implement sparse matrix and do some decompositions like Cholesky Decomposition, LU Decomposition, QR Decomposition on it.

Actually I found a library called JAMA which is capable of doing this for dense matrix.

But I have to implement sparse matrix.

Can any one share their experience implementing sparse matrix or is there any library to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/) or [Matrix-Toolkits-Java](http://code.google.com/p/matrix-toolkits-java/)? These may help you out.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [la4j](http://la4j.org) (Linear Algebra for Java) library that supports sparse matrices. The la4j uses the most common and effective sparse representaions sush as [CRS (Compressed Row Storage)](http://netlib.org/utk/papers/templates/node91.html) and [CCS (Compressed Column Storage)](http://netlib.org/utk/papers/templates/node92.html). Here is the corresponding classes in la4j: [CRSMatrix](https://github.com/vkostyukov/la4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/la4j/matrix/sparse/CRSMatrix.java) and [CCSMatrix](https://github.com/vkostyukov/la4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/la4j/matrix/sparse/CCSMatrix.java). So, you can look into sources or use la4j's sparse matrices directly with mentioned decompositions.

Here is the brief example:

```
Matrix a = new CRSMatrix(new double[][]{
    { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 },
    { 0.0, 2.0, 0.0 },
    { 0.0, 0.0, 3.0 }
});

Matrix[] qr = a.decompose(Matrices.QR_DECOMPOSITOR); // qr[0] = Q, qr[1] = R

Matrix[] u = a.decompose(Matrices.CHOLESKY_DECOMPOSITOR); // u[0] = U
```

Comment: This solution is outdated.